# Buffer and variable Element undeclared (first use in function)

Tags: c++, class, buffer, element

[Implementation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XbFrA.png)

[Class](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o8JDV.png)

Hey guys, so I'm working on a code and I keep getting "element" and "buffer" an error saying theyre undeclared. No idea why, pictures of code/errors above.

Comment: Do not post your code as image. Post your code directly as text.

Comment: I think the compiler says that `element` and `buffer` are undeclared because they are undeclared.

Comment: I think it's just a typo.  Looks like `element` should be `elements`.

Answer (score 0):

Your class only declare these variables:

```
int *elements;
int *size;
```

But 'element' and 'buffer' are undeclared Really!

if are they global variables or others?